# SSRS custom code

Tags: reporting-services, custom-code

I'm having an issue in my SSRS report.  What I'm trying to accomplish is get a correct summary total for a particular group, on field `ClaimNumber`

How the particular formula works is based on other fields in the record, and on of those values being zero:

```
=iif(Fields!FieldA.Value=0,0,Fields!FieldA.Value-Fields!FieldB.Value-Fields!FieldC.Value)
```

So if `FieldA` is zero, the displayed value is `0`, otherwise it displays `FieldA-FieldB-FieldC`.

This works fine for each individual `lineitem`, but the summary totals on the grouping on `ClaimNumber` are incorrect, as in some cases the `FieldA` value under that particular `ClaimNumber` is `0`, sometimes not.  So I'm having trouble summing on the `ClaimNumber` grouping total, as the summary does not know which records `FieldA` is `0`, and which are not.

There must be an SSRS custom code formula that would work in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap a `Sum` function around your expression, or even around each individual column in the expression, it's only going to evaluate that once. In other words, this describes the issue you're having where it's not accounting for some of the rows having 0 in FieldA. One way to correct this is to make your expression a calculated field on your dataset. Then you can Aggregate the calculated field to get totals and subtotals. Since it is a calculated field, it will be evaluated row by row to get the correct total. So the good news is: no custom code!

Comment: Hi Steve - I get an error when creating a calculated field and trying to do a summation.  The calculated field(called "contract amount") within the dataset reads: =iif(Fields!FieldA.Value=0,0,Fields!FieldA.Value-Fields!FieldB.Value-Fields!FieldC.Value).  This works fine in each individual row, but when I try to use aggregate summation in the group within the table - using =Sum(Fields!contract_amount.Value, "groupfield") - I get an error- ONLY on a summation which contains a row where FieldA is zero.  ALL other summation by group calculate correctly.  Very non descriptive "#Error".  Any ideas?

Comment: Try simply `=Sum(Fields!contract_amount.Value)`

Comment: @Scott Values A, B, C are integer or decimal? Try =SUM(iif(Fields!FieldA.Value=0,Cdec(0),Fields!FieldA.Value-Fields!FieldB.Value-Fields!FieldC.Value))

Comment: Awesome!  That worked.  Looks like it DOES make a difference, int vs decimal.  Thanks to both of you!